# Are the Facebook API Key and App Secret the same thing?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am using a WordPress theme which requires entering an Facebook API key in order to enable comments.  I created a new Facebook app, but all it's showing me is an App ID, API version, and an "app secret."

Do I need to enter the app secret in place of the API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Key is the API ID.
The API secret is the API secret.

That theme is using legacy terminology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Please up the question, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: @RandyS: Please don’t beg people to upvote your questions. That is just annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The App ID should be your API Key. The App Secret is different. Some plugins I've found require both in separate fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have given it a vote.  Please upvote the question, if it's not too much trouble.